# Parse Server: Which ports do I need to open in my firewall for ios push notifications? (APNS)

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, port, firewall, parse-server

I try to setup `parse` on my own server. I got it up and running.

Which ports do I need to open in my firewall for ios push notifications via APNS?

I found this info on the web:

> 1. TCP port 5223 (used by devices to communicate to the APNs servers)
> 2. TCP port 2195 (used to send notifications to the APNs)
> 3. TCP port 2196 (used by the APNs feedback service)
> 4. TCP Port 443 (for https access to the API)

I could not find any poof somewhere else. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple provides a [full list](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944) of ports used by its software and products.

The ports 2195, 2196 and 5223 are used by APNS according to this list.

But you still have to open port 443 for wi-fi only network, according to this Apple [support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203609) :

> If you use Wi-Fi behind a firewall or a private Access Point Name (APN) for cellular data, you'll need a direct, unproxied connection to the APNs servers on these ports:
>
> - TCP port 5223: For communicating with Apple Push Notification services (APNs)
> - TCP port 2195: For sending notifications to APNs
> - TCP port 2196: For the APNs feedback service
> - TCP port 443: For a fallback on Wi-Fi only, when devices can't reach APNs on port 5223

Comment: Which of those need to be incoming and which outgoing?

Answer (score 0):

You need below port open for ios push notifications via APNS:

**TCP port 2195 (used to send notifications to the APNs)**